# Environment variable modification through QTP scripting

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, qtp

I have admin rights for example, I can modify system variables directly. But I am failing to do the same through VB scripting like

```
On error resume next
Dim objShell, RegLocate 
Set objshell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
Set objEnv=objShell.Environment("System")
msgbox objEnv("USERNAME")
objEnv("USERNAME")="SAI"
msgbox objEnv("USERNAME")
Msgbox err.number&"msg::"&err.description
Set objshell = Nothing
```

Output

```
error 70.permission denied
```

Please help me to understand

Comment: What version of QTP/UFT is this? And how are you opening QTP? I have tried this without issue and did not have to open UFT with "run as administrator" (which, incidentally, you could try).

Comment: This should not happen if you have admin rights. If it does, you have an admin alias which is capable of all rights, but hasn´t got them all. Also, registry policies might forbid changing system environment variables.

Comment: Also it would be useful to know which statement exactly yields the error.